# HAProxy create custom routing logic

Tags: haproxy

Is it possible to write a custom routing logic for HAProxy. I need it in such a way that each application server is allocated a max on 1000 TCP connections then only should the loadbalancer try to route next TCP request to next application server.

if not with HAProxy if there any other Load balancer that can do it please let me know.

Can persistence be applied to TCP connections. There will no HTTP request.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes,  this is possible. You want the `balance first` statement in your `backend` or `listen` section. You will also need to assign a `maxconn` value for each backend server.

Here is an example configuration:

```
listen kumarServer
    bind *:80
    mode tcp
    balance first
    default-server maxconn 1000
    server kumar1 10.0.1.21
    server kumar2 10.0.1.22
    server kumar3 10.0.1.23
```

And yes, tcp connections can have persistence. But you are limited to source ip address.

---

Based on your comment that you need to monitor certain parameters on the servers to decide which server to load balance the clients to, you should look at the `option httpchk` in combination with `http-check expect` or `http-check disable-on-404`. You could also use `option lb-agent-chk`.

Let's look at `option httpchk` and `http-check disable-on-404`. To make this work, your application should expose a simple status webpage that returns an HTTP status of 200 if the server is available for new connections, or 404 if no new connections should be opened. `stick on src` will allow users who already have active connections to keep their connection, and to reconnect if their connection is lost.

```
listen kumarServer
    bind *:7000
    mode tcp
    balance first
    stick on src
    default-server maxconn 1000
    option httpchk
    http-check disable-on-404
    server kumar1 10.0.1.21 check port 80
    server kumar2 10.0.1.22 check port 80
    server kumar3 10.0.1.23 check port 80
```

Comment: can you please elaborate on this. I have not used HAProxy before

Comment: see my edit that includes a sample configuration

Comment: thanks will look into it does HAProxy have any option for custom load balancer proxy where we can write custom logic code for load balancing policy

Comment: Fully custom? No. But if you tell me what behavior you need, it might be supported by haproxy's built-in options.

Comment: from what you have mentioned HAProxy may not be able to but this is what i need. I need to load balance mmo (massive multiplayer online) server. There are lot of conditions but on a high level max users connect to a server is 1000 and also number users per rooms per server. based on these conditions optimally route the user to the server. If you know of any suggestion or know of any other load balancer please let me know.

Comment: see edit................

Answer (score -1):

None of HAproxy's builtin load balancing algorithms cater to your use case, nor does it provide any means for creating your own custom algorithm.

The only way you'd be able to do this in HAproxy is to modify the source to provide this functionality.